# Opening New IE Session using Window Toolbar

Tags: internet-explorer, session, qtp

I am trying to open a new IE session while one session is already open in UFT. I want to open it by clicking on File - New Session from the current IE Window.

I am trying the below code, but it is not able to click on File :

```
Browser("abc").WinToolbar("ToolbarWindow32").highlight
Wait 4
Browser("abc").WinToolbar("ToolbarWindow32").Press "&File"
Wait 4
Browser("abc").WinMenu("ContextMenu").Select "New session"
```

Can some please suggest what is wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

IE 9 and above does not work perfectly with QTP.

First downgrade to IE 8. Then make sure you have selected "Record and run test on any open browser" in the Record and Run Setting under Automation.
Also make sure the Menu Bar in IE is not hidden.

I was able to open new session with below code:

```
Browser("<Page Name>").WinToolbar("ToolbarWindow32").Press "&File"
Browser("<Page Name>").WinMenu("ContextMenu").Select "New Session"
```